# Proving some probability identities

Tags: probability

I was hoping someone could help me with the following. Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two events such that $\Pr(B)\neq 1$ I want to prove that

$\Pr(A\cap B)\geq \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-1$

$\Pr(A)>\Pr(A|B)\quad \textrm{if}\quad \Pr(A)<\Pr(A|\overline{B})$

$\Pr(A)<\Pr(A|B)\quad \textrm{if}\quad \Pr(A)>\Pr(A|\overline{B})$

The hint given is to first prove

$\Pr(A|\overline{B}) = \frac{\Pr(A)-\Pr(A\cap B)}{1-\Pr(B)}$

which I managed to do. But I don't see how this is useful in proving the other three things.

Comment: For the first question, consider what values $P(A\cup B)$ can take on, and the relationship, if any, between $P(A\cup B)$, $P(A)$, $P(B)$, and $P(A\cap B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P(A)<P(A|\bar{B})=\frac{P(A)-P(A\cap B)}{1-P(B)}$, then if you multiply this out and manipulate it a little, you get that $P(A\cap B)<P(A)P(B)$. But then $$\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}<\frac{P(A)P(B)}{P(B)}=P(A).$$ The reverse inequality should be the same proof with the inequalities reversed.

Now for your first inequality, you know that $A\cup B=(A\setminus(A\cap B))\cup B\subseteq S$, where $S$ is your sample space. Since $P(S)=1$, you know that $$P(A\cup B)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)+P(B)\leq P(S)=1.$$